# How to make parameter mandatory in Axis2?

Tags: xml, web-services, configuration, wsdl, apache-axis

I am creating a web service using Axis2 in Eclipse. When I deploy my web service, the WSDL file is autogenerated. However, some of the parameters of my web service method should be mandatory? How do I make the parameters mandatory? Can it be configured at services.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Do arguments check at the beginning of the method, and try to handle the exceptions properly with relevant exception messages, for the arguments which a user passes.

Suppose you have a parameter like 'city', which is sent as null or "", you can do a check in the code which you've written and throw an exception saying info is mandatory(in the implementation file which you've written).

Thus, when the user doesen't send mandatory parameters, he should get relevant exception messages. I had done the same with WS I created and am not sure if there are any other ways of achieving the same.

Comment: That's what I'm also doing right now. But I am thinking if there's a way to let Axis2 handle it. So there's no need for the request to enter the actual method if there is a missing parameter.